# Average number of random stat increases to go from base to cap, where chance of increase reduces as stat nears cap

Tags: probability, random

Ok, so I have a game where you have 3 stats: agility, strength, and stamina.  I'll avoid going into tons of detail about the game, so here's the gist of the math:

Each stat starts at `1`.  Every time you send a message, there is a random chance for a stat to increase by `1`.  The chance is calculated as follows:

First: The stat to try and increase is randomly selected.  Equal probabilities.

Second: If the stat is at its cap (`200`), then nothing happens.  No stats gained.  Otherwise, the stat has a random chance equal to `(200 - current stat) / 200` of increasing by `1`.

What I want to know is, how many messages will it take, on average, for the stat to hit max?  If you can tell me the same info with a starting stat of 200 each, and cap of 455 each, that would be lovely as well.  If your formula applies to both, I can... probably use it?  It's almost 2am, I'm kinda fried.  Not sure what to tag.  Anywho, thanks :) hope this is fun.

Comment: "Every time you send a message, there is a random chance for a stat to increase by 1." - does each stat have this chance to increase, or just one at a time?

Comment: just one at a time.  As I put in the process list, first it picks one of the stats at random, *then* applies the random chance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured this out on my own (after sleeping haha).  I was really tired so I had to stupid-simple explain it to myself, and I'll write that here for fun and for the tired readers.

When you flip a coin, you have a 1/2 chance of getting heads.  That means, for every *2* flips, you get *1* heads.  2 flips / 1 heads = 2 flips per head.

When you get a stat increase, you have a `(200 - current stat) / 200` chance of getting the stat to increase by 1.  So, for every 200 opportunities, you will get `(200 - current stat)` increases.  `200 messages / (200 - current stat) stats` = X messages per stat.

So, when my stat is 1, it's (200/199) messages to get it to increase to 2.  When it's 2, it's (200/198).  All the way up to when my stat reaches 199, and it will take (200/199) messages to get it to hit 200.

So, for one stat, the average number of messages to max it are:

`(200/199) + (200/198) + ... + (200/2) + (200/1)`

Which can also be written as:

`The sum from i=1 to 199 of (200/i)`

And this is easily changed for a start of 200 and a goal of 455 (I wrote 405, I meant 455, my bad):

`The sum from i=1 to 454 of (455/i)`

In the end I just plugged these into wolframalpha, I'm sure there's a formula for the sums but I'm too tired to remember that or my answers.  Anyways, thanks for reading :) lmk if you have questions.